# Bootstrap Form Helper how to initialize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i downloaded this plugin but i dont have a clue how to make it working ?
I included all nececery files bootstrap and helper also.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd">
```

but still i did not get any results like on their website? Where i m wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the `CSS` before the `JS`.

Normally, you put the `CSS` in the `<HEAD>` and the `JS` before the `BODY`.

You can put the JS in the HEAD but make it after the CSS declarations. The formhelpers JS uses the CSS, which is why it has to be before.

Then in your BODY where you want your control, you need to use a DIV not an INPUT, because formhelpers is controlling it using the DIV iirc

```
<form class="form-inline">
   <div class="bfh-phone" data-format=""></div>
</form>
```

Hope that helps.